# Handling JWT authentication in React app

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I'm trying to implement a restricted route with `react-router v4` and I'm almost done, but I need to handle validation of JWT token and don't know where to put this.

**RestrictedRoute**

```
const RestrictedRoute = (props) => {
  const { component, ...otherProps } = props;
  return <Route {...otherProps} component={component} />;
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  authenticated: state.authentication.session,
});


const branched = branch(
  ({ authenticated }) => !authenticated,
  renderComponent(() => <Redirect to="/login" />),
);

const enhanced = compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  branched,
)(RestrictedRoute);

export default enhanced;
```

So with this I'm able to redirect users to `/login` page if the `state.authentication.session` is set to `false`. Until now I was checking if there is a `jwt` cookie and setting this `session` based on that. This had some simple vulnerability as you could add `jwt` cookie with any value, and you will be considered as authenticated.

I created an endpoint for validating my `jwt` token and created an action for this. My question is - where to put this?

If I put this in `componentWillMount` of `RestrictedRoute` and a authenticated user tries to visit a restricted page he is showed the `login` page and then switched to the restricted route, as the response from the endpoint changes the redux store.

Answer (score 1):

do you want to validate your token in each of your RestrictedRoute? why?!

you don't need to validate your token for changing a route even if your react -route is restricted.

**you have to validate your token for getting data on the server by write a policy or middle-ware for that API.**

with this method you can just checking a cookie for validate it in react-route.. if hackers put the data on your cookie, they can access to that react-route but they cant see the data

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I handled it by validating the token on the server (as I do server side rendering) and passing the data to my redux store.